# Хранение матрицы в файле

Tags: c, массивы, файлы, матрицы

как записать матрицу с рандомными числами в файл?

```
int x[4][4]; 
srand(time(0)); 
int i,j; 
FILE *thirdd; 

thirdd = fopen("C:\\Users\\Jeka\\Desktop\\text.txt","r+"); 

for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) { 
    for (j = 0; j < 4; j++) { 
        fprintf(thirdd,"%d",x[i][j]==rand()%21-10); 
    } 
} 
fclose(thirdd);
```

Comment: Используйте одну из функций файлового вывода. С чем конкретно у вас проблема?

Comment: Не понимаю как записать матруцу которую заполнил, в файл

Comment: Записать как текст, как бинарный? Покажите, кстати, в каком виде вы ее создали.

Comment: int x[4][4];
   srand(time(0));
      int i,j;
 FILE *thirdd;
 thirdd = fopen("C:\\Users\\Jeka\\Desktop\\text.txt","r+");

    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
        for (j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        {
           fprintf(thirdd,"%d",x[i][j]==rand()%21-10);
        }
}
fclose(thirdd);                                             написал так но в файле 000000000000000000

Answer (score 2):

Итак,

```
fprintf(thirdd,"%d",x[i][j]==rand()%21-10);
```

Что же мы пишем в файл? Ага, результат сравнения `x[i][j]` и `rand()%21-10`.

Вряд ли они совпадают, так что записываем "ложь" в виде ноликов...

Кстати, если не хотите после исправления получить новые неприятности - разделяйте числа, не пишите их в одну строку слитно, без пробелов и прочего...

P.S. Для любителей минусовать и кричать "не содержит ответа" разжевываю по буквам: нужно писать

```
for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) { 
    for (j = 0; j < 4; j++) { 
        fprintf(thirdd,"%d ",x[i][j]=rand()%21-10); 
    } 
    fputs("\n",thirdd);
}
```

Comment: Еще можно перед выводом элементов матрицы вывести ее размерность

Comment: @avp Лично я бы предпочел к вашему дополнению еще и бинарный файл...

Comment: Тогда может понадобиться еще и про BOM (и вообще про переносимость) понятным для новичка образом рассуждать...

Comment: @Harry, кажется, Вы немного "сэкономили" в строке `fputs("",thirdd);` на `\n` внутри кавычек ;-).

Comment: @Vladimir А, да, по привычке `puts`... Спасибо!